# How can I get value from dynamically generated select options?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the value of a selected option that is dynamically generated. If I hard code the whole thing it works  [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G7uQZ/44/). But dynamically nothing works. When I select the option nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

**markup**

```
 <button type="button" id="connect" onclick="login();">
 <select id="pages" style="display:none;" onchange="getPage();"></select>
```

**js**

```
//open login dialog onClick
function login() {  
FB.login(function(){
  FB.api('/me/accounts/',  function(response) {
            var pages = document.getElementById('pages');
            pages.style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("connect").style.display="none";
            for(var i =0; i < response.data.length; i++)
            {
              pages[i] = new Option(response.data[i].name,response.data[i].access_token);
            }

          }
        );

}, {scope: 'manage_pages'});
}

function getPage(){
    var e = document.getElementById("pages");
    var f = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;    
    alert(f);
}
```

Comment: var id = $('#pages').find('option:selected').attr('value'); should pull out the value - if undefined check the values being constructed dynamically and that the attribute 'value' is being set.

Comment: @user685590: you mean to use it alone in the getPage() function? Tried it created same effect and I dont use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You may try to the following:

Replace

```
 pages[i] = new Option(response.data[i].name,response.data[i].access_token);
```

With

```
pages.options[pages.options.length]=new Option(response.data[i].name,response.data[i].access_token);
```

Comment: thanks for trying the code is good but does not work at firing the alert.

Answer (score 0):

After several tests, turns out there is nothing wrong with the initial code. The problem was that I only had one option which couldn't fire the event. To solve that problem I added an empty option to the select.

Adding this did the trick:

```
  document.getElementById("pages").insertBefore(new Option('', ''), 
          document.getElementById("pages").firstChild);
```

For full answer see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928169/how-can-i-add-an-empty-option-in-a-select-tag-created-dynamically)